# How often can I perform high intensity interval training per day?

Tags: exercise-frequency, high-intensity

I am currently beginning with HIIT and so can't take to its full intensity. 
I was wondering can ( rather, should ) I do it multiple times in a day, say 2 to 3 (perhaps even more) times in a day or should I stick to just once a day?

Currently, I am following an cardio HIIT where I do exercise for 1 minute, then rest for 30 secs. and then go for 1 more minute. After that, I am completely exhausted as I am a complete beginner.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to improve your work capacity.  The following work pretty well:

- Start with longer rest times, and shorten them each time.  For example 1m work, 2m rest for one session.  Then 1m work, 1.5m rest the next session.
- Multiple times a day.  Essentially this is a variation of the previous point where some of the rest is much longer.
- Keep the intervals the same, but try to get a bit more work done each time.  You may be totally gassed and only able to get 1-2 reps of whatever you are doing, but the next time it gets easier.

The key point is to get all the work in.  You can improve over time, and probably the best bet is to keep shortening the rest times until you can get through everything.  If you have to take a longer break, like 5-10m between cycles of work, that's fine when you are getting started.

Now, one of the aspects of "insanity" and P90X brands of HIIT is that you attempt to improve your work capacity with the intervals.  No matter what you are doing: burpees, tire flipping, sledge hammer work, snatches, etc.--as you get stronger, and your body gets used to the conditioning aspect of the HIIT, it will become easier.  Your heart rate will come down to normal more quickly, and your body won't get tired as easily.

Answer (score 2):

Consider doing each movement at less than 100% of failure and then your conditioning improves increase you can levels. Also use longer breaks in between movement as need but not to long. These breaks will also reduce inverse to the increase in stamina.

It sounds like you have a structure routine that will do overall body or groups of muscles. If you only can do the first two or three movement of ten for your program you are not getting the designed full routine targeted area worked done.

So by going less than 100% for each movement to start and getting through whole routine should be much better for overall body and muscle development than 100% of just a few exercises within a daily routine.

Start slow, listen to your body, not your EGO. Work on getting through a daily routines and add as you go. Keep good journals of your progress. There is nothing that says after completing a daily routine if you are still feeling energized you can't add in a few more reps.

Hope this helps you getting started.